# bootstrap-select detras de input text

Tags: bootstrap

Tengo un problema con varios bootstrap-select los cuales despliegan la lista de valores por detras de otros input text del mismo formulario.

Se pueden ver varios ejemplos similares del mismo fallo

http://jsfiddle.net/brzu9hh4/

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/8XAdW

¿alguna ayuda de como solucionarlo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Efectivamente es un problema [reportado en varias ocasiones](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/760) en Bootstrap cuando se usan varios grupos de `select-picker` en un mismo contenedor, las listas quedan una posición debajo de los `input`.

Lo primero que podríamos intentar es usar la propiedad `z-index` a nuestro favor, aumentando su valor en las listas desplegables, o disminuirlo (o eliminarlo) en el texto que está quedando superpuesto, pero [no sería el uso correcto](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/760#issuecomment-396811845).

La [solución](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/760#issuecomment-62349896) que se ofrece es la siguiente:

```
.input-group .bootstrap-select.form-control {
  z-index: inherit;
}
```

> Para las propiedades heradadas el valor [`inherit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/inherit) refuerza el
>   comportamiento del valor por defecto y es necesario sólo para anular
>   otras reglas.

```css
.input-group .bootstrap-select.form-control {
  z-index: inherit;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../docs-assets/ico/favicon.png">

        <title>TEST</title>


        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/web.css">
        <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/non-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

      </head>


      <body>

        <!-- Fixed navbar -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
          
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="/search/">TEST</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapsible">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
              
                <li class="active"><a href="/search/">Home</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="get" action="/snearch/" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sid" placeholder="e.g. hello">
                        <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" type="submit"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="container">

          <form class="form-horizontal" action="/snps/" method="POST" role="form">
      <div style="display:none;"><input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="1413008961.84##d5f5a444ea1ef9d7ed3268e2e554bde2d2cc21e3"></div>
        <div class="input-group"> 

          <span class="input-group-addon">Test1:</span>
          <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" id="test_select" name="test_name">
                <option value="">--- Select One ---</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <BR/>   
        <div class="input-group"> 
          <span class="input-group-addon">Test2:</span>
          <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" id="test2_select" name="test2_name">
              <option value="">--- Select One ---</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
          </select>
        </div>      
        <BR/>   
        <div class="input-group">   
          <span class="input-group-addon">Test3:</span>
          <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" id="test3_select" name="test3_name">
                <option value="">--- Select One ---</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
          </select>
        </div>      
        <BR/> 
        <div class="input-group">   
          <span class="input-group-addon">test4:</span>
          <select class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow form-control" data-live-search="true" id="test4_select" multiple data-max-options="2" name="test4_names">
                <option value="">--- Select One ---</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
                <option value="">Test</option>
          
          </select>
        </div>      
        <BR/>      
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Start position:</span>
          <input class="form-control" id="start_pos" name="start_pos" placeholder="e.g. 200" type="number" value="">
          <span class="input-group-addon">End position:</span>
          <input class="form-control" id="end_pos" name="end_pos" placeholder="e.g. 1000" type="number" value="">
        </div>
        <BR/>    
        
        <div class="input-group">       
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
          </span>
        </div>
    </form>

        </div> <!-- /container -->

      <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

      </script>  
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Perfecto. Muchisimas Gracias :-)